# Javascript replace method, replace with "$1"

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm reading Sitepoints 2007 book "Simply Javascript" and I encountered some code I just can't understand.

It's the following code:

```
Core.removeClass = function(target, theClass)
{
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^| )" + theClass + "( |$)");
    target.className = target.className.replace(pattern, "$1");
    target.className = target.className.replace(/ $/, "");
};
```

The first call to the replace method is what puzzles me, I don't understand where the "$1" value comes from or what it means. I would *think* that the call should replace the found pattern with "".

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Each pair of parentheses `(`...`)` where the first character is not a `?`* is a "capturing group", which places its result into `$1`,`$2`,`$3`,etc which can be used in the replacement pattern.

You might also see the same thing as `\1`,`\2`,`\3` in other regex engines, (or indeed in the original expression sometimes, for repetition)

These are called "backreferences", because they generally refer back to (an earlier) part of in the expression.

(*The `?` indicates various forms of special behaviour, including a non-capturing group which is `(?:`...`)` and simply groups without capturing.)

In your specific example, the $1 will be the group `(^| )` which is "position of the start of string (zero-width), or a single space character".

So by replacing the whole expression with that, you're basically removing the variable `theClass` and potentially a space after it. (The closing expression `( |$)` is the inverse - a space or the string end position - and since its value isn't used, could have been non-capturing with `(?: |$)` instead.)

Hopefully this explains everything ok - let me know if you want any more info.

Also, here's some further reading from the site [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info):

- [Groups and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Atomic Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) (doesn't work in JS, but interesting)
- [Lookaround groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (partial support in JS regex)

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now.

I had a little trouble understanding what you meant by "each pair of parentheses", but that applies to the regex pattern. If the regex pattern contains a pair of parentheses then it's a capturing group.

Answer (score 12):

$1 is a backreference. It will be replaced by whatever the first matching group (set of parenthesis) in your regex matches.

Comment: In this case $1 will be nothing (if the first group matches the 0-width ^ start of line character) or a space (if the first group matches a space).

Comment: No, it is **not** called a back reference. It's called a "special replacement pattern".

Comment: How to add a $ sign using this pattern?